# How to set CUDA on Yosemite?

Tags: gcc, cuda, nvcc, osx-yosemite

I have upgraded to Yosemite but `nvcc` doesn't like the new `gcc4.9`

```
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0
In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin/../include/cuda_runtime.h:59:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin/../include/host_config.h:82:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.7 and up are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.7 and up are not supported!
```

I'm using an old GeForce9400M but the driver is working. 
This is the DeviceQuery compiled with nvcc 5.0:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce 9400M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          6.5 / 5.0

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 6.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce 9400M
```

This is the DeviceQuery compiled with nvcc 6.5:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.dylib
  Referenced from: /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/./deviceQuery
  Reason: Incompatible library version: deviceQuery requires version 1.1.0 or later, but libcudart.dylib provides version 0.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

How should I set Yosemite to use CUDA?

Comment: What you are trying to do can't work. CUDA 5.0 isn't compatible with Yosemite, and neither are the Xcode/SDK versions that provide the host toolchain CUDA 5.0 needs.

Comment: NVIDIA says that driver support for older generation GPUs with SM1.x has been deprecated. Following these instructions https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/627626/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-driver-on-mac-os-mavericks/post/4138126/#4138126 my driver still works. Do you think I can use CUDA 6.5 with SM1.x on Yosemite?

Comment: Finally, it works after installing CUDAToolkit6.0 downgrading CUDAdriver to 4.2.10, and then upgrading only CUDAdriver to 6.5... I still get a warning `nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.` I guess that means I should not upgrade to 6.5 Toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1) installing CUDAToolkit6.0

2) downgrade CUDAdriver to 4.2.10,

3) upgrade CUDAdriver to 6.5 ONLY!!!...

I still get a warning nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.

I asked this on a nvidia tutorial and the answer was "Hardware Update"

Hence I will stay away from 6.5 Toolkit or new updates.